# Dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, 4 partitions problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I need to install Ubuntu for Odin project, but my laptop already have 4 partitions used. I read that solution to this problem might be to delete one of partitions but I am not sure how that would affect Windows.

My partitions:

[image]

I know I shouldn't delete my `C:` and `E:` but what about my **484 MB** partition?

Comment: I can do that, but when I try to install Ubuntu this part of partition is marked as unusable

Comment: @Mostafa I used disk management and made an 80Gb partition from C:. Then tried to install Ubuntu. When my installation came to the part where I needed to chose partition on which to install, my 80 Gb partititon was marked as unusable and couldn't be marked.  Later I expanded my C to it's 80Gb

Comment: I think the problem is you already have 4 primary partition (which means no more partition you can have on it) remember that Ubuntu needs to make another partition for swap. So, You need to make one extended partition at the end of your Hard Disk in which later you can make two partition, one for ubuntu and one for swap. I think this is why you get error while installation

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Search for "making extended partition in YOUR_OS".

Comment: An extended partition counts against the primary partition count on the drive; if it's MBR it will limit you at 4 partitions, and you're out of luck.  If your system is EFI, then you can just resize your E drive downwards to have more space for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to delete partitions. It is strange that you have it installed in four primary partition. Anyway, that is not a problem: You can create an extend partition for Ubuntu. You are limited to 4 primary partition but you can create many extend partition.

> but what about my 484MB partition?

Do not delete it! it might be to recover the system or the EFI system partition. The only partition you do not need is the :E disk. :C is for the sytem as you know, :E is for storing personal datas. 
In your case you could or delete :E to install ubuntu, or resize :C.
To resize :C launch your live media with ubuntu and select "try ubuntu without instaling" Once you've done that launch "gparted" form the dash and resize your :C partition. With 100GB you have more than enough if you do not stock to much personal files in your ubuntu.

Comment: I tried but it gives me warning, saying that I have 4 primary partition and if I want to make extended I need to delete one

Comment: I think you would be best figuring out exactly what all these partitions are, you can do this by mounting them from your live media and inspecting what is on them. It is unusual to have 4 primary partitions from the factory, I assume you are currently running a windows OS. Also you would be best resizing your windows partitions from windows if possible to reduce the chance of future problems.

Comment: You cannot resize a partition that is mounted and the only partition in this case to play with is the :C one. So it cannot be done from the installed windows system: It has to be done in live mode.